# How to make SSHD start early in Fedora?

Tags: fedora, boot, sshd

I'm having trouble booting Fedora 24. Virtual Box fails to load, and then there appears to be some sort of Plymouth or GNOME problem:

[image]

When the machine hangs like this, I attempt to SSH into it from another machine:

```
$ ssh 172.16.4.34
ssh: connect to host 172.16.4.34 port 22: Connection refused
```

I'm less concerned about the boot problem, but more concerned about lack of SSH access. If I can't get into the box, then I can't fix it. (And I've found trying to figure out rescue commands is a complete waste of my time. In the above, I've edited the rescue boot commands so it *does not* perform `load_video`, which appears to to be ignored because GNOME is still loaded).

When I setup SSH on Fedora, how do I tell it to start early in the boot process so I can gain access to the machine even when there are GNOME, Plymouth and Virtual Box problems?

Comment: Run dropbear from initramfs. http://roosbertl.blogspot.com/2012/12/centos6-disk-encryption-with-remote.html

Comment: You are showing us a picture of the machine's console.  You appear _to have_ access to the machine, no SSH needed.  Log in on a ordinary TTY login on one of the virtual terminals, or boot to rescue or emergency modes, or use the systemd "kbrequest" hotkey that starts up a rescue login.

Comment: Thanks @JdeBP - As stated above, rescue mode is useless. It can't even stop the suspect component from starting. And I have no energy to sort through all the useless posts on trying to figure out how to properly use some of these modes. I would much rather have SSH start so I can use it. No research and learning is required.

Answer (score 2):

Fedora uses systemd for the boot process, and systemd doesn't order things explicitly — in fact, it *already* attempts to start everything *as early as possible*. You could possibly force it to start before those other things by mucking with the dependencies, but I don't think there's any point. That's because this parallel process *also* means that if there is a problem with something that isn't in the blocking path (and GNOME is not a dependency of sshd), it won't stop sshd from starting.

So, if sshd *isn't* starting, something else is going on, and trying to make it start earlier won't help.

Comment: Thanks. Its not the answer I wanted to hear... Unfortunately, I have no command line or SSH access, so I can't tell what is going wrong.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I'm not a VirtualBox user so I can't really help much. I guess... things I'd try are: F25 instead of F24 to see if it works any better. Or, boot with `systemd.unit=multi-user.target` (or just `3`) on the kernel command line to force it into non-GUI mode to simplify things.